# Plot.ly - Multiple Traces to same Key in Legend

Tags: plotly

I have been using plot.ly and would like to group multiple traces to the same key in the legend.
I have subplots that show data about a particular user. Id like to have each key represent a user rather than user.data1, user.data2, etc.

Here is an example of what I have now:

[image]

I would like to group all 1s in to their own key, all 2s to their own key, and all 3s to their own key.

This part of my code demonstrating how I am currently doing the traces

```
trace1_A = go.Scatter(x=file1.a, y=file1.b, name='1') #plot1
trace1_B = go.Scatter(x=file1.c, y=file1.d, name='1') #plot2
trace1_C = go.Scatter(x=file1.e, y=file1.f, name='1') #plot3
trace1_D = go.Scatter(x=file1.g, y=file1.h, name='1') #plot4
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Here is the final view of my solution adding `legendgroup`, `marker=dict(color='')`, as well as `showlegend` led me to the desired outcome.**

```
trace1_A = go.Scatter(x=file1.a, y=file1.b, name='1', legendgroup='1', marker=dict(color='red'))
trace1_B = go.Scatter(x=file1.c, y=file1.d, name='1', legendgroup='1', marker=dict(color='red'), showlegend=False)
trace1_C = go.Scatter(x=file1.e, y=file1.f, name='1', legendgroup='1', marker=dict(color='red'), showlegend=False)
trace1_D = go.Scatter(x=file1.g, y=file1.h, name='1', legendgroup='1', marker=dict(color='red'), showlegend=False)
trace2_A = go.Scatter(x=file2.a, y=file2.b, name='2', legendgroup='2', marker=dict(color='blue'))
trace2_B = go.Scatter(x=file2.c, y=file2.d, name='2', legendgroup='2', marker=dict(color='blue'), showlegend=False)
trace2_C = go.Scatter(x=file2.e, y=file2.f, name='2', legendgroup='2', marker=dict(color='blue'), showlegend=False)
trace2_D = go.Scatter(x=file2.g, y=file2.h, name='2', legendgroup='2', marker=dict(color='blue'), showlegend=False)
trace3_A = go.Scatter(x=file3.a, y=file3.b, name='3', legendgroup='3', marker=dict(color='green'))
trace3_B = go.Scatter(x=file3.c, y=file3.d, name='3', legendgroup='3', marker=dict(color='green'), showlegend=False)
trace3_C = go.Scatter(x=file3.e, y=file3.f, name='3', legendgroup='3', marker=dict(color='green'), showlegend=False)
trace3_D = go.Scatter(x=file3.g, y=file3.h, name='3', legendgroup='3', marker=dict(color='green'), showlegend=False)
```

Answer (score 7):

I think `legendgroup` is what you're searching for:

```
trace1_A = go.Scatter(x=file1.a, y=file1.b, name='1', legendgroup='1') #plot1
trace1_B = go.Scatter(x=file1.c, y=file1.d, name='1', legendgroup='1') #plot2
trace1_C = go.Scatter(x=file1.e, y=file1.f, name='1', legendgroup='1') #plot3
trace1_D = go.Scatter(x=file1.g, y=file1.h, name='1', legendgroup='1') #plot4
...
```

Comment: Thank you. This combined with `marker=dict(color='')` and `showlegend` gave me my desired outcome.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing but with multiple traces from several dataframes. like this:

`for c in df_aT.columns:
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[c]*len(df_aT[c]),y=df_aT[c],
legendgroup='1', mode='markers'),name='P_1'))

for c in df_bT.columns:
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[c]*len(df_bT[c]),y=df_bT[c],
legendgroup='2', mode='markers'),name='P_2'))`

This is then repeated multiple times, one for each of 4 more traces. Is it possible to only display one instance in the legend for each group? Right now it displays a legend entry for every point I plot. @vlizana